# Angular highlight text after mouse selection

Tags: angular

I need to create a feature to highlight text after mouse selection, with additional possibility to remove highlight. Text comes from a backend, and can have multiple html tags so it is inserted into a component as innerHtml.

I did use `document.execCommand('HiliteColor', false, "yellow")`, as it is the simplest solution and handles highlight selection across multiple paragraphs and spans.
But the solution is not working as expected for firefox.

[Demo avaliable here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-my1hom)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    document.onmouseup = () => {
      this.onSelectEventHandler();
    };
  }

  private onSelectEventHandler(): void {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    if (selection && selection.type == 'Range') {
      const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
      if (range) {
        if (this.isSelected()) {
          this.setColorToRange('unset');
        }
        else {
          this.setColorToRange('yellow');
        }
      }
    }
    selection.empty();
  }

  private isSelected(): boolean {
    //temp
    return false;
  }

  private setColorToRange(color: string): void {
    document.designMode = 'on';
    if (!document.execCommand('HiliteColor', false, color)) {
      document.execCommand('BackColor', false, color);
    }
    document.designMode = 'off';
  }
}
```

Any suggestion for solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Your example appears to work in Firefox, when `document.designMode = 'off';` gets commented out ...? (It works from the _second_ selection on, but not on the first one. But that might be a problem with the rest of the logic.)

Comment: Why you do not use Angular inseated of js ? I mean why bother to use angular if you will ignore its advantages and mix everything and make it even harder to debug